# Highest ordinal enum value

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I'm looking to compute the highest ordinal enum value from a list of enum properties in a list of beans.

For example, I have:

```
@Data
public class MyBean {
    private Priority priority;
}
```

and

```
public enum Priority {
    URGENT("Urgent"),
    HIGH("High"),
    MEDIUM("Medium"),
    LOW("Low");

    @Getter
    private final String value;

    Priority(String value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return getValue();
    }
}
```

If I have a `List`of `MyBeans`, how can I find the max ordinal value of the bean's `priority` in the list?

Example:

```
   {myBean1, myBean2, myBean3, myBean4} where

    myBean1.getPriority() = Priority.LOW
    myBean2.getPriority() = Priority.URGENT
    myBean3.getPriority() = Priority.HIGH
    myBean4.getPriority() = null

    returns Priority.URGENT
```

I'm thinking the worst case is that I could iterate the `values()` in the enum starting with `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(Priority.values()));` and loop through each bean to see whether the value matches.  But this seems tedious.

Comment: Don't base code around the order in which your enums are declared. Someone will come along in a few months and say "wouldn't it be nice if these were in alphabetical order??" and unexpectedly break your code.

Comment: Understood.  I have it commented, for now, to make sure the order isn't changed.  In the future, we'd move toward using the actual string and a `Comparator`.

Comment: Do you want to process all the beans, but in priority order?

Comment: `URGENT` is the *min* ordinal in this case.

Comment: @Bohemian No, I just need the highest priority in all of the beans.

Comment: Also, **do not use null as a sentinel value**. If a return value is optional, it should be declared as `Optional<>` so that it's explicit. But in this case that doesn't make sense to me anyway. How can something have *no priority*? You should add a case for called "Default" priority or "Lowest" priority.

Comment: "No priority" is the case where it's not set by the user.  If I take your comment further, it would mean initializing with a default priority of `Untagged` or `Not Selected` or `Unknown` rather than using null.

Comment: Can you have a `PriorityQueue` instead of a `List`?

Comment: @bphilipnyc What's stopping you implementing the getter as: `getPriority(){ return (priority != null) ? priority : Priority.DEFAULT; }`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - no limitation on the data structure, but my existing code returns a `List`.

Comment: @Michael - correct, that's another way (and a better way to do it)

Comment: @Michael, would you mind updating your answer to reflect the `Priority.DEFAULT`?  I will accept it.  There are multiple (strong) solutions to this problem, though I felt yours would lessen the chance of future issues.

Comment: @bphilipnyc Alright, done! Hope it helped you.

Comment: @Michael - disagree. The order in an enum matters. Not only does Java define a comparator over enums; systems like Hibernate can use an enum's order for persistence or serialization. It would be quite unwise for someone to reorder an enum without first ensuring the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Doradus Just because Hibernate is popular and is implemented in a certain way doesn't mean that it's automatically a great implementation and that it's a good idea to emulate them. Library authors are fallible and write bad implementations all the time. Have you seen large portions of the JDK (j.u.Date and Vector are the obvious examples)? Maybe *with the current state* of things like Hibernate it would be unwise to do such a refactor nonchalantly but it *should not* be that way. We should be able to do that safely. Writing code that relies on such features makes you part of that problem.

Comment: @Michael - Enum explicitly implements Comparable and has an `ordinal` method that tells you the value's position within the enum.  It's impossible to be sure reordering doesn't matter without looking at all the code that uses the enum. Hibernate is just one example of a real system that relies on enum ordinals.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: @Doradus "stuff relies on ordinals" is not an argument against the statement "stuff should not rely on ordinals"

Comment: @Michael - You're entitled to your personal preferences, of course, but it is a fact that enums in Java are ordered. They implement Comparable and have ordinals. Some code makes use of this fact and some doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would give each priority a specific numeric value and add a method which can compare them. Unfortunately enums can't implement Comparable (for consistency) which is a bit of a bummer here.

The fact that you are returning null sentinel values complicates things slightly. I would rethink this if I were you. Consider a "Default" priority instead which can act as our priority if one is missing.

I've added the default priority as a totally unique option, but depending on what you want you could just use medium or low as the default.

```
public enum Priority {
    URGENT ("Urgent", 10),
    HIGH   ("High",    5),
    MEDIUM ("Medium",  2),
    LOW    ("Low",     0),
    DEFAULT("Default",-1);

    @Getter
    private final String name;

    private final int value;

    Priority(String name, int value) {
        this.name  = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    public int compare(Priority that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.value, that.value);
    }
}
```

You will then need to change your priority getter to return this new default rather than `null`, else we'll get null pointer exceptions later on.

```
public class MyBean {
    private Priority priority;

    // Never returns null :)
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return (priority != null) ? priority : Priority.DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

Now we've done the "hard" work, getting the highest priority is super easy:

```
Priority max = Collections.max(beans, (a,b) ->
    a.getPriority().compare(b.getPriority())
).getPriority();
```

Comment: Good reminder of the new `Collections` methods. In this case, it is indeed sufficient and much simpler. @bphilipnyc Just pay attention to empty lists, as this method throws an exception in this case instead of returning null.

Comment: @MalteHartwig `Collections.max()` is not new. But it's noteworthy that enums implement comparable out of the box; you don't need to explicitly check the ordinal.

Comment: Your comparison logic is incorrect. If `a` and `b` are both null it should return 0.

Comment: You shouldn't break the interface contract, even if it's safe for a particular use case.

Comment: @shmosel Agreed but there is no interface contract in this case. I can define `safeCompare` however I like. Granted, following the convention of `compareTo` is much more sensible.

Comment: Your lambda implements `Comparator.compare()`, which does have a contract.

Comment: @shmosel A callee does not just inherit a contract because of how its called. The function exists independently of any knowledge about the manner in which it is used. It either fulfills an existing contract (interface) or it provides a new one. The caller can decide whether that fulfills their requirements. The *only question* is "is this a good function?" Without `return 0` it wasn't, but now it is.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting your static method needs to follow some contact. I was saying the lambda failed to follow *its* contract by delegating to your static method. Agreed that it's correct now.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Stream API and especially the `max(Comparator)` method to find the bean with the highest priority.

*Note: your enum has the priorities in reverse ordinal order. In my example, I will assume the opposite to make the code more self-explanatory. Switch `max` for `min` and `nullsFirst` with `nullsLast`, if you do not re-arrange your enum.*

```
Bean highest = beans.stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparing(Bean::getPriority,
                                              Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Priority::ordinal))))
                    .orElse(null);

return highest.getPriority();
```

If you only need the priority, you can simplify:

```
return beans.stream()
            .map(Bean::getPriority)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Enum::ordinal))
            .orElse(null);
```

It works as follows:

1. Look at every bean
2. Take its priority
3. Discard null priorities
4. Pick the maximum priority
5. Beware of the list being empty or all priorities being null

*Note: My examples are very verbose. shmosel's (deleted) answer shows that you can order enums naturally by `ordinal`, making for nicer comparators.* `Comparator.comparing(Enum::ordinal)` can just become `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: Why is the Trend of the Month to use streams when it is both horrible to read and inefficient?

Comment: Well, I personally think streams make a lot of things easier to understand (once you get used to reading them) because pretty much every word has meaning. Sure, everyone knows how to implement this with classic local variable/for loop fashion, but it is boilerplate that needs to be read in order to make sure it really just is boilerplate without "hidden" surpises.

Comment: And regarding the efficiency, I find a lot of places in our code where using streams well might offset some of the performance impact by omitting the creation of multiple temporary collections and variables. And depending on the use case, performance might not even be an issue. As long as I do not crunch enormous amounts of data or feel pressure otherwise, I always go for readability and maintainability.

Comment: "streams make a lot of things easier to understand". You then proceed to have a 5 point list having to explain what the hell is going on.

Comment: *"Why is the Trend of the Month to use streams when it is both horrible to read and inefficient?"* ... I used to think as you do, but when you adjust to the new fluent style and the new functional style, I think it is possible to agree that streams are typically easier to read since the code declares its intent.  With imperative coding, one can lose the intent in the details of how its done.  As far as efficiency, that it's worse is a claim which is far, far harder to substantiate.

Comment: @Michael That's a courtesy in case OP is inexperienced and because code-only answers are frowned upon. Anyone who's used streams a bit can read it very easily. The second example especially is much clearer than an equivalent loop.

Comment: @bphilipnyc That is correct, thanks. I focussed on the second example too much and forgot to check in the first one. I will correct the example.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it's not much of an improvement after making it null-safe. You would need to do `Comparator.comparing(Bean::getPriority, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())))`, which isn't even shorter than your comparator.

Answer (score 3):

Another safe way to do it would be to use `Ordering` from [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained) as a way to define an `explicit` order, without relying on the Enum `ordinal` that can change as others have pointed out.

```
 // creates an explicit Order (from left to right)
 Ordering<Priority> order = Ordering.explicit(Priority.LOW,  
                 Priority.MEDIUM, 
                 Priority.HIGH, 
                 Priority.URGENT)
                .nullsFirst();

List<MyBean> list = Arrays.asList(new MyBean(Priority.HIGH), 
                   new MyBean(null), new MyBean(Priority.URGENT));

Priority p = list.stream()
        .map(MyBean::getPriority)
        .max(order)
        .orElse(null);

System.out.println(p); // Urgent
```

Comment: But it would need to change with future additions to the `Priority` enum, right?  For example, if we added `Priority.EXTRA_LOW`, we'd need to know to add it to this `order`?  (I'd assume a unit test would catch this if we tested for it.)  To be clear, I don't dislike the solution.

Comment: @bphilipnyc indeed it would have to be changed. U could put that comparator inside the enum itself as a static method and have a unit test that fails as you say.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of `MyBean` elements that have a `priority` attribute and you also need to get the highest element from that list, according to this priority.

If you only need to do this once, then you can use `Collections.max` with a suitable comparator and you will be done.

But if you need to get this highest element many times, or, if after getting this highest element, you also need to get the second highest element, then you could perfectly use a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

```
Queue<MyBean> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(myComparator);
queue.addAll(myBeanList);
```

Where `myBeanList` is the list containing all your `MyBean` instances and `myComparator` could be defined as follows, according to your requirements:

```
Comparator<MyBean> myComparator = Comparator.comparing(
    MyBean::getPriority,
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Then, you could use your queue to get the element with the highest priority by means of the [`PriorityQueue.peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek--) method:

```
MyBean highest = queue.peek();
```

This gets but not removes the highest-priority element.

If you want to get and remove the element from the queue instead, you should use the [`PriorityQueue.poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll--) method:

```
MyBean highest = queue.poll();
```

Comment: Your comparator handles null beans, not null priorities.

Comment: Nice.  You can weaken the type on the left side to just `Queue<MyBean>`.