# How can I find the biggest value in the response?

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, collections, enums

I have the following response
how I can go throught it to find the biggest card Rank? Card Rank it is Enum
The goal: find the biggest card to know who wins in the game

```
[Hand(player=Player(name=Tesla, money=1300), firstCard=Card(rank=CARD_2, suit=DIAMOND), secondCard=Card(rank=CARD_5, suit=HEART)), Hand(player=Player(name=Uber, money=1500), firstCard=Card(rank=CARD_4, suit=SPADE), secondCard=Card(rank=CARD_4, suit=CLUB))]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highest ordinal enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880803/highest-ordinal-enum-value)

Comment: No, cause I'm not sure how can I go through this response

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom compare method, and then combined it with a divide and conquer algorithm to find the maximum value in the array.

---

#### Compare

```
public int compare(Card card1, Card card2) {
    if () {
        // card1 should rank at the beginning, return a negative integer
    } else if () {
        // card2 should rank at the beginning, return a positive integer
    } else {
        // card1 & card2 rank the same, return 0
    }
}
```

#### findMax (Divid and conquer)

The [Divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) approach will find the maximum value, by finding the maximum value in two sub-arrays, and then comparing the two.

```
Card findMax(Card[] cards, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end) return null; 
    else if (start == end) return cards[start]; 
    else if (start + 1 == end) {
        int c = compare(cards[start], cards[end]);
        return c <= 0 ? cards[start] : cards[end];
    } else {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2; 
        Card m1 = findMax(cards, start, mid);
        Card m2 = findMax(cards, mid + 1, end);
        int c = compare(m1, m2);
        return c <= 0 ? m1 : m2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the following solution: val maxHand = hands.maxBy { it.firstCard.rank.ordinal }

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution with maxBy{}

```
val maxHand = hands.maxBy { it.firstCard.rank.ordinal }
```

Answer (score 0):

Goal: find the winner who has bigger card.

**First**: define Data structure,Omit constructor and getter/setter methods:

```
public class Card {
    private CardRank rank;
    private String suit;
}
```

```
public enum CardRank {
    CARD_2(2),
    CARD_4(4),
    CARD_5(5);

    private int val;

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    CardRank(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

```
public class Hand {
    private Player player;
    private Card firstCard;
    private Card secondCard;
}
```

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int money;
}
```

```
public class PlayerWithBigCard {
    private String name;
    private CardRank rank;
```

**Second:** use Java 8 stream API to find the player we want(omit init codes):

```
Optional<PlayerWithBigCard> winner = hands.stream().map(hand -> {
    PlayerWithBigCard playerWithBigCard = new PlayerWithBigCard();
    playerWithBigCard.setName(hand.getPlayer().getName());
    CardRank firstCardRank = hand.getFirstCard().getRank();
    CardRank secondCardRank = hand.getSecondCard().getRank();
    if (firstCardRank.getVal() - secondCardRank.getVal() > 0) {
        playerWithBigCard.setRank(firstCardRank);
    } else {
        playerWithBigCard.setRank(secondCardRank);
    }
    return playerWithBigCard;
}).max(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getRank().getVal()));

winner.ifPresent(playerWithBigCard -> System.out.println(playerWithBigCard.getName()));
```

ps：Java Strem provide many simple method for us to operate data,you can find docs from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)